# Anscheinend ist das Perfekt verschiedener Modalverben verschwunden. Warum?

Tags: evolution

- Warum erscheinen *gesollt, gemusst, usw.* im Deutschen nicht? [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLQjs.jpg)
- Warum existieren die nur in Konjugationstabellen?
- Oder vielleicht wäre es interesanter zu wissen, wann man diese Tempora richtig nutzen kann. Ich habe die weder in der Zeitung, in Romanen, in Fachbücher gelesen noch in gesprochene Sprache gehört.

  ---

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLQjs.jpg) Ich basiere auf Folgendes. Um die Behauptung zu unterstützen, kann man mithilfe *Ngrams* deren Frequenz mit der Frequenz der Präsens-Formen vergleichen. Die Rechnung macht man mit der Formel

[image]

Dann vergleicht man die Verhältniszahlen für Modalverben mit den Verhältniszahlen der quasi „üblichen“ Verben.

Das Ergebnis [ist:](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28gegeben%2F%28gebe%2Bgibst%2Bgibt%2Bgeben%2Bgebt%2Bgegeben%29%29%2C%28gemacht%2F%28machen%2Bgemacht%2Bmache%2Bmachst%2Bmacht%29%29%2Cgedurft%2F%28d%C3%BCrfen%2Bgedurft%2Bdarfst%2Bdarf%2Bd%C3%BCrfet%29%2C%28gesollt%2F%28sollen%2Bsoll%2Bsollst%2Bsollt%2Bgesollt%29%29%2C%28gemusst%2F%28m%C3%BCssen%2Bmuss%2Bmusst%2Bm%C3%BCsst%2Bgemusst%29%29&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28gegeben%20/%20%28gebe%20%2B%20gibst%20%2B%20gibt%20%2B%20geben%20%2B%20gebt%20%2B%20gegeben%29%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28gemacht%20/%20%28machen%20%2B%20gemacht%20%2B%20mache%20%2B%20machst%20%2B%20macht%29%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28gedurft%20/%20%28d%C3%BCrfen%20%2B%20gedurft%20%2B%20darfst%20%2B%20darf%20%2B%20d%C3%BCrfet%29%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28gesollt%20/%20%28sollen%20%2B%20soll%20%2B%20sollst%20%2B%20sollt%20%2B%20gesollt%29%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28gemusst%20/%20%28m%C3%BCssen%20%2B%20muss%20%2B%20musst%20%2B%20m%C3%BCsst%20%2B%20gemusst%29%29%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

Nicht dass die Rechnung genau ist, aber mit einem Vielfach größer als 1000

[image]

ist es klar, dass die Perfekt-Formen kaum auftauchen.

Comment: Ausserdem... mach doch mal den Test für "sein"... du kannst nicht einfach sagen "Die tauchen nicht auf." Sprache ist eine Pareto-verteilung... bloss weil was selten ist, heißt das nicht, dass es nicht da ist. Das Wort "gesollt" ist häufiger als das Wort "Brunft" https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Brunft%2Cgesollt&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CBrunft%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgesollt%3B%2Cc0... gibt es das dann auch nicht? B

Comment: @Emanuel Ach Quatsch! Ich vergleiche Verben mit Verben.   *Sein* ist echt speziel. Kannst du das Verb deiner Wahl vergleichen: Seine Kurve geht nicht niedriger als die Kurve der genannten Modalverben. Ausserdem lautet im Titel *verschiedener*, nicht *aller* Modalverben.

Comment: Wie auch immer... sie sind nicht verschwunden, sondern waren nie wirklich da... siehe meine Antwort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Gewollt aber nicht gekonnt. 
>   Das ist gekonnt zubereitet.
>
> Ich habe meine Katze sehr gemocht.

*Wollen, können, mögen* - diese 3 Modalverben kommen häufig genug im Partizip 2 vor.

*Gesollt* und *gemusst* sind in der Tat ziemlich rar. Jedoch sind sie nicht verschwunden.
Die Perfektformen waren nie richtig da.

Ich glaube es hat etwas damit zu tun, dass es von diesen Verben nicht wirklich eine perfektive Idee gibt. Ursprünglich gab es für alle Verben nur das Präteritum. Zusätzlich gab es das Präfix *ge-*, das die Idee von *fertig* dazu gab. Unter dem Einfluss von Latein ist dann das Perfekt entstanden und *ge-* wurde zum Marker Nummer 1.
Für die Modalverben gibt es aber nicht wirklich einen perfektiven Zustand.

> Ich habe fertig gewollt.

Das heißt nichts. Daher ist es verständlich, wenn diese selten bis nie mit *ge-*verwendet wurden. Und daran hat sich bis heute wenig geändert. Wobei es da im südlichen Sprachraum schon anders aussieht.
Das gleiche Phänomen findet man übrigens bei Verben wie *finden*.

> Ich fand den Film gut.

Dieses *finden* hat keinen perfektiven Zustand. Ergo wird auch heute (zumeist) noch das Präteritum verwendet.

> Ich habe das Handy gefunden.

Das hat einen perfektiven Zustand. Ich habe das Handy. Hier wird Perfekt verwendet.
Mit Sprachökonomie hat das ganze allerdings wenig zu tun denn

> Ich trank

ist auch kürzer als

> Ich habe getrunken.

Und früher, bei Aufkommen des Perfekt, waren alle Präteritumformen den Leuten durchaus geläufig. Sie hatten ja nur das.

Answer (score 1):

Modalverben werden viel häufiger benutzt als andere Verben. Die Präteritumsform ist kürzer als die Perfektform. Es ist für Modalverben also ökonomischer, die Präteritumsform zu benutzen als die Perfektform, weil die enorme Einsparung durch kürzere Form den erhöhten Aufwand der Unregelmäßigkeit übertrifft.

Comment: Hinzu kommt, dass die entsprechenden Sätze nicht gerade schön sind, z. B.: »Ich habe zur Schule gehen sollen.«

Comment: Danke Toscho, aber wenn du die Frage dir genauer ansiehst, ist der Vergleich nicht mit der Präteritumsform (ich hatte schon sowas für das Präteritum von *sein* und *haben* gefragt). Ich vergleiche mit z.B. *sollen* hier: *Ich denke, dass du deine Jacke seit langem hättest kaufen sollen*.

Comment: Du willst also Indikativ Perfekt und Konjunktiv Perfekt vergleichen?

Comment: Was ist das denn für eine seltsame Argumentation mit Einsparungen? Meinst Du, die Sprache wird immer kürzer und kürzer? Wieso startet man nicht schon kurz?

Comment: @userunknown Die Ökonomisierung von Sprache ist ein Sprachentwicklungsgesetz.

Comment: Deswegen sagen die Leute auch so gerne "in 2013" statt "2013" oder "zeitnah" statt "schnell, flugs, rasch". Oder "die Tasche von Susi" statt "Susis Tasche".

Comment: Ökonomisierung bezieht sich nicht nur auf die Menge an benötigten Buchstaben, Silben oder Wörtern, sondern auch auf die grammatikalische Komplexität. Der Genitiv in „Susis Tasche“ ist komplizierter als die Präpositionalkonstruktion „die Tasche von Susi“. Des Weiteren ist die Ökonomisierung nicht das einzige Sprachentwicklungsgesetz. Und da Linguistik nun mal keine Mathematik ist, gelten die Gesetze nicht unbedingt, sondern stellen Modelle dar.

Comment: Was ist an "Susis Tasche" komplizierter? "s" gegen "die" + "von"

Comment: @Emanuel Der Dativ ist dem Genitiv sein Tod.

Comment: Ne, mal ernsthaft... was ist daran komplizierter?

Comment: Ich habs dir doch gesagt: Für den Großteil der Bevölkerung ist `von+Dativ` einfacher als `Genitiv`.